# .NET 5 on IIS - Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetAgent, Version=1.0.0.0'

Tags: iis, .net-5, webapi

.NET5 applications throwing error after deploying to IIS.

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetAgent, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87b69d96e75fbfca'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'DotNetAgent, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87b69d96e75fbfca'
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at AG.MatterSphere.Web.API.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: How did you publish it? What parameters were given to `dotnet publish`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to "Enable 32 bit Applications" in Application Pool to solve this issue.

1. Select Application Pools under the Web Server name in the left window.
2. In the Application Pools window, right-click AppPool and select Advanced Settings.
3. Under the General section, set Enable 32-Bit Applications to True.
4. Click OK to save the changes.